# Undefined Variable Loop

Tags: python

I am new to Python. 
I get an error that says "undefined Variable". I could not figure it out. 
The statement in the code is the following:

```
Classroom1 = Classroom(FirstCourseStartTime = 8, LastCourseEndTime = 7.75)
m_count = 0 
h_count = 0
t_count = 0
l_count = 0
loopsize = 10000
Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)
def Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize):
    for i in range(0, loopsize):
        Mutated = Classroom()
        Mutated = Classroom1.CopyOfClassroom(Mutated)
        Mutated.Mutate()
        HardConstraintClassroomMet = Classroom1.ComputeHardConstraint()
        HardConstraintMutatedMet = Mutated.ComputeHardConstraint()
        if HardConstraintClassroomMet == False and HardConstraintMutatedMet == False:
            h_count + 1
            t_count + 1
            Classroom1.Mutate()
            continue
        if Mutated.FitnessValue() > Classroom1.FitnessValue():
            m_count + 1
            t_count + 1
            Classroom1 = Mutated
        if Classroom1.ComputeHardConstraint() == False:
            l_count + 1
            temp = l_count*loopsize
            print "Unable to meet hard consraints in %d" % temp
        Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)
```

Comment: I think, you are calling the function 'Loop' before defining it.

Comment: Perhaps it means that the variable Python tells you is undefined (which you have neglected to tell us), might be undefined? Python will also tell you the line at which it's trying to use the undefined variable; maybe defining it earlier than that line would help. Could be worth adding even a dummy definition above that line such as `Loop = 0` and seeing whether you at least get a different error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling your `Loop()` function before you have defined it.

Comment: In addition, where's the Classroom class?

Comment: Further to this, you seem to be infinitely and exponentially recurring over the `Loop` function (assuming all lines of code after your `def Loop` line are supposed to be indented by one).

Comment: Looks like the indentation's been fixed and you are indeed invoking infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to organize:

```
class classroom,
    def loop
```

Inside your function loop write in globals:

```
global m_count
global h_count
global t_count
```

and finally change the if statements:

```
if HardConstraintClassroomMet == False and HardConstraintMutatedMet == False:
        h_count = h_count + 1
        t_count = t_count + 1
```